# Accepting Date in a Text_Field instead of date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a form that let's you set the date for an event. I am using the date_select form helper so I have 3 select drop downs.

I thought that maybe I could just switch it to a text_field and format the date and validate with a regex, but it seems I can only input it as dd/mm/yyyy. If I input 12/25/2012 for example - it returns an error (of blank, because I guess it doesn't have another error type?) Can I get it to accept format as mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.parse(the_textfield)`, you don't need to write your own regex.
rdoc here on how it works:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/parse/class

You can add this as a before-save method in your model thus:

```
before_save :parse_date_string
def parse_date_string
  my_date = Date.parse(my_date) if my_date.is_a? String
end
```

Comment: Would that go in my model some place or in my controller on update and create?

Comment: Up to you. I generally put it as a before_save method in my model. That way it will always happen - no matter where you get the date from... but you then have to check if the input is already a Date

Comment: Instead of using `if my_date.is_a?(String)` I'd suggest to do `Date.parse(my_date)` and then rescue the error so you can show the validation errors (if there are any).

Comment: The point of the check is not bother parsing if we already have a Date object. Date.parse doesn't play nice if the object is already a Date